# Can't remove gradient in grouped UITableView background on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

Ever since upgrading to iOS 6, I'm getting this odd gradient on the background of a grouped UITableView that I have in the headerview of another UITableView (which doesn't have the same gradient problem). This is what it looks like:

[image]

You can see it at the bottom of the table showing "Full Name", "Company", "Title". Is anyone else having this problem / does anyone know how to remove the gradient?

I've already tried setting the table's background color and background view's background color, but neither of these solutions has worked. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a little late but recently I've had the same problem and finally discovered that

`[[self mTableView] setBackgroundView:nil];`

for your added Grouped table will solve the problem.